# Is every object destroyed when widget is refreshed?

Tags: android, android-widget

I have widget that looks like this:

```
public class WidgetMain extends AppWidgetProvider {

public LocationListenerClass locationListener = null;
private static final String WIDGET_CLICKED    = "widgetClickTest";



  @Override
public void onEnabled(Context context) {

    super.onEnabled(context);
     Intent intent = new Intent(context,WidgetMain.class);
     intent.setAction(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE);

     int[] ids = {R.xml.widget_provider};
     intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS,ids);
     context.sendBroadcast(intent);
}





@Override
  public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
      int[] appWidgetIds) {
    if(locationListener == null){

        Log.d("onUpdate", "locationIsNull=true");
    }
    Log.d("onUpdate", "isCalled=true");

    }
  }





@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onReceive(context, intent);
    if(WIDGET_CLICKED.equals(intent.getAction())){
        if(locationListener != null){
        locationListener.getSingleUpdate();
        }
    }
}





@Override
public void onDeleted(Context context, int[] appWidgetIds) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDeleted(context, appWidgetIds);
    locationListener.destroy();
}
```

}

Well,
When I run(and also when It receives update broadcast) my app I get both locationIsNull=true and isCalled=true in debug log, so my question is. Is the object destroyed between updates of widget?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your process can and usually will be terminated between updates of the app widget. The new process will not have any of the static data members from the old process.

Comment: @zarcel: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html

Comment: So what's the solution?

Comment: @zarcel: Get rid of `locationListener`. After all, you are never assigning anything to it, so it will always be `null`. And, even if you *did* assign something to it, since an `AppWidgetProvider` instance is only used for one event (e.g., one `onUpdate()` call), there is no point in having a data member. Beyond that, since `LocationListenerClass` is your own class, I do not know what it does and whether or it is appropriate for use by an `AppWidgetProvider`.